# Gmail API call returning blank with no errors, but not applying change for delegate creation

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to call the Gmail API in App Script while impersonating a user account using [Google's Oauth2 library for App Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs) to set a delegate for their inbox. Using Google's examples as a base, I created the following function to call the service and provide the right information to create a new Delegate on an inbox:

```
function setGmailDelegate() {
  var formObject = {
    delegateReaderEmail: "homer.simpson@fox.com",
    delegateTargetEmail: "robert.terwilliger@fox.com"
  };

  var userEmail = formObject.delegateReaderEmail;
  var boxEmail = formObject.delegateTargetEmail;
  Logger.log("Letting "+userEmail + " read " + boxEmail);

  var service = getGmailAddDelegateService_(boxEmail);
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + boxEmail +'/settings/delegates';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      body: {
        "delegateEmail": userEmail,
        "verificationStatus": "accepted"
      }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(result);
  } else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
  }
}
```

This function returns **nothing** - there's no error message but the delegate is not created. According to the API I should be getting a [delegates resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates) back but I'm not. What am I doing wrong?

This is the function that defines the OAuth service creation:

```
function getGmailAddDelegateService_(boxEmail) { 
  return OAuth2.createService('Gmail:' + boxEmail)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate.
      .setSubject(boxEmail)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope(['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing']);
}
```

I've tried changing the scopes around but to no avail. I can't see anything in the execution logs of the G Suite audit logs that point to any issues.

Comment: I guess you don't get any output because of the `if (service.hasAccess())`. This condition is probably false. Do you get the output of the first Logger? Regarding the Oauth part, the github example is for domain-wide delegation with Service Accounts , which requires to have a paid G Suite account. Is that your case?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a paid G Suite account and I've setup the domain wide delegation account and authorized it with all the scopes I need. I did get output when I had the scopes wrong here, but now I just get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: URLApp requires that your specify you're POSTing data:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
      },
      body: {
        "delegateEmail": userEmail,
        "verificationStatus": "accepted"
      }
```